# JavaFX - GridPane Background Image

Tags: java, image, url, javafx, background-image

I've been searching around the internet, and I still haven't found a solution.

All I want to do is: Set an image to my GridPane in a POPUP-window, that I've made, when a button is clicked.

Some programmers refers to:

```
grid.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url('URL')");
```

Which were my suggestion as well, but it does not seem to work. 
I've also tried to set 
`Image image = new Image();` 
and then set an ImageView, but with no luck!

Hope someone in here has a quick fix for this answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//root.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url('https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQxsasGQIwQNwjek3F1nSwlfx60g6XpOggnxw5dyQrtCL_0x8IW')");

This worked out. But not all url's it likes.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using FXML, you have to add stylesheets to your GridPane in the Controller class. For example, `gridPane` is the reference variable of your GridPane and `app.css` is a name of your stylesheets:

```
gridPane.getStylesheets().addAll(getClass().getResource("/css/app.css").toExternalForm())
```

Then write something like this in your stylesheets:

```
#gridPane { -fx-background-image:url("file:C:/path/to/your/project/folder/src/main/resources/image.jpg"); }
```

In addition, you can add stylesheets `app.css` to GridPane in the SceneBuilder.
The aforementioned procedure worked for me.